# Become user in server environment to test cloud code

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to login a User with `User.logIn`, because I want to test all my cloud code functions with Mocha and expect.js.

I know I can use the masterkey, but I want to test if my errors are handled correctly when I'm logged in with a wrong user (basically I want to test what happens when the ACL blocks the request).

I've tried logging in with cURL and that works, but then I can't become the user because Parse blocks that through `It is not memory-safe to become a user in a server environment`.

Is this simply not possible or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I was overlooking something.

In the [changelogs](https://parse.com/docs/downloads) of the JS SDK at V.1.5.0 you can see that Parse added the error message described above. You can bypass that by using `Parse.User.enableUnsafeCurrentUser();`.

You can also provide the session token in the function options.

Comment: Thank you SO much for posting this... couldn't find anything about running a cloud function as a user.  Do you know why this is 'memory unsafe'?

Comment: Without this, utilizing ACL dramatically limits code reuse as you have to do everything from the Client side and nothing in Cloud Code